# What is the equivalent Camera2 API for setPreviewTexture() API?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have been trying to get the GL Texture and generate a SurfaceTexture from it, and provide to the Camera destination end, so that i can use Texture in the shader program to render.

Before Camera2 API, i could see the API below.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)

I have been hunting the equivalent API for Camera2 API. Could someone provide the hint? Or any alternative say something like, using setSurfaceTexture(SurfaceTexture openGLMappedSurfaceTexture) of TextureView?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder
                    = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
```

Please refer this sample for a better understanding:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java